# radio default button auto submit

Tags: php, html

I have created a form using radio button and using checked for default radio button.i want to auto submit default button. But i'm not getting it. Here is my code -

```
 <p><u>Location<u></p>
                <form method="post" action="amazon.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="level" value="B1" <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'level']) && $_POST[ 'level']=='B1' )?>onclick="this.form.submit()">Basement 1</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="level" <?php if (isset($_POST[ 'level']) && $_POST[ 'level']=='L1' )?> value="L1"checked="checked"onchange="this.form.submit();">Level 1</label>
                </div>  
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Care to explain this further? What do you mean by **I want to make auto submit default button**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is there is no space between the  value="L1"checked="checked" on the second radio causes the error. And use radio button group to group the radio buttons.

Comment: I tried with space between value and checked but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Change the event from `onchange` to `onclick`.

Corrected Code:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="level" 
<?php if (isset($_POST[ 'level']) && $_POST[ 'level']=='L1' )?> 
value="L1" checked="checked" onclick="this.form.submit();">Level 1</label>
```

You have default checked the `L1` radio.

And `onchange` event is called on it.

If you click on `L1`, it should be `checked` if not `checked`.

But, being already checked, no change happening, therefore, no form submit is occurring.

If you change the event to `click`, it will trigger on click only irrespective of it is `checked` or `unchecked.`.

Comment: Thanks pupil but i want to auto submit it. I mean that when i'll host the page checked value should submit automatically. I have used onclick as well but i don't want to click on option. As i have checked value L1 so it should submit automatically value L1.